# How do you create a shortcode function to run a script within a page?

Tags: php, ckeditor

I am using ckeditor for a custom cms solution. It works well enough but i'd like to set it up so that the admin can enter some formatted text code in the textarea like

```
{print gallery[1]}
{run gallery.php[1]}
{do gallery.php[1,2,3]}
{gallery.php?id=1&opt=3}  // preferred
```

and it will convert the code to print the output of a gallery script, gallery.php, with the provided options. On the display page if I do something like:

```
$text = str_replace ("{","<?php",$text);
$text = str_replace ("}","?>",$text);
```

this breaks the page. Using str_replace works fine for simple substitutions, perhaps formatting, but not here as is.

Notes added: 2018-05-17

I used preg_match as suggested and this gets me closer to a usable solution. I added the following text into the textarea field called introtext as an administrator might:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus mollis convallis justo, vitae pretium libero condimentum et. {simple-gallery.php 1 3} Morbi nibh nibh, blandit sit amet sodales ullamcorper, ultricies vel nulla. {simple-gallery.php 2 3} Quisque cursus erat eu felis vulputate, scelerisque tempor libero egestas. Inte ger vitae dignissim odio, eget congue mauris. Suspendisse mattis efficitur sem, ut sagittis magna sodales eu.
```

In my script I used preg_match and then split the result and got:

```
text_to_be_replaced: simple-gallery.php 1 3
Match found and text extrapolated:
script: simple-gallery.php
arg1: 1
arg2: 3
```

I am able to successfully include the simple-gallery.php file and display the first slideshow using include. At this time when I print out the textarea it is printing the bracketed text. I can possibly solve that by doing a str_replace and stripping out the text, at least for the first occurrence.

However we will need the versatility to add multiples galleries in the textarea and free text above, below and in between as seen in the introtext. My code:

```
preg_match_all("/\{(.+?)\}/", $introtext,$results);
$array1 = $results[1];
$text_to_be_replaced1 = "$array1[0]";
$split1 = explode(' ',$text_to_be_replaced1);
$script1 = $split1[0];
$arg1 = $split1[1]; // if needed
$arg2 = $split1[2]; // if needed

echo $introtext; // returns everything including the bracketed text
include ("$script1");
```

Notes added 2018-05-20

I revised the code; it is working to add a parameterized gallery or video script but somewhat out of sequence in addition to outputting a 1 (the number 1) in the text area where the gallery code belongs. The revised code:

```
preg_match_all("/\{(.+?)\}/", $introtext,$results);

foreach($results[1] as $gallery){
  $split = explode(' ',$gallery);
  $arg1 = isset($split[0]) ? $split[0] : -1;
  $arg2 = isset($split[1]) ? $split[1] : -1;
  $arg3 = isset($split[2]) ? $split[2] : -1;
  $html = include ("$arg1");
  $introtext = preg_replace("/\{" . $gallery . "\}/", $html, $introtext);
}

echo $introtext;
```

It displays like:

```
gallery #1
gallery #2
gallery/video #3

text
1
text
1
text
1
```

See the demo at: http://www.dottedi.biz/demo/code/public/shortcode/shortcode.php

Comment: Best option would be to use regex for this.
An example would be `preg_match_all("/\{(.+?)\}/", $your_string, $results);

And then parse your result as such and display the gallery

Comment: I added some progress notes; still need help in both setting up the output to show the introtext and multiple iterations of using the shortcode in the correct position.

Comment: I added some additional progress notes. It's getting much, much closer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
want to improve above answer:

preg_match_all("/\{(.+?)\}/", $introtext, $results);
foreach ($results[1] as $gallery) {
    $split = explode(' ', $gallery);
    $arg1 = isset($split[0]) ? $split[0] : -1;
    $arg2 = isset($split[1]) ? $split[1] : -1;
    $arg3 = isset($split[2]) ? $split[2] : -1;

    ob_start();
    include "$arg1";
    $html = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $introtext = preg_replace("/\{" . $gallery . "\}/", $html, $introtext);
}
echo $introtext;
---------------
```

Answer (score 0):

After using the regex: `preg_match_all("/\{(.+?)\}/", $introtext,$results);`

You can do something like this:

```
foreach($results[1] as $gallery){
    $split = explode(' ',$gallery);
    $arg1 = isset($split1[0]) ? $split1[0] : -1; // if needed && check if the parameter exists before trying to access it
    $arg2 = isset($split1[1]) ? $split1[1] : -1; // if needed && check if the parameter exists before trying to access it
    $html = 'your code for the gallery';
    $introtext = preg_replace("/\{" . $gallery . "\}/", $html, $introtext);
}
```

Which will replace the instance of {gallery.php 1 2} with your actual gallery code. And then move on to the next match an do the same again, where you would just need to pass your arguments to the gallery code.